# Is this chain of inequalities correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, transformation

Is this chain of inequalities correct? If not how to make it works?
$$\frac{\ln \left( 1+x^3+y^3 \right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le  \frac{\left( x^3+y^3 \right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \le \frac{ \left( x+y\right) \left( x^2+y^2\right) }{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{\left( x+y\right) \left( x^2+y^2\right) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^2}= \left( x+y \right) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: I think the intention is $x,y>0.$ But why do have all those extraneous $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ terms? This is all you're trying to show: $\ln (1+x^3+y^3) \le x^3 + y^3 \le (x+y)(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: I've just multiplied top and the bottom by denominator and the denominator is given in a question.

Comment: it seems to be ok